How to write a Haskell function that can call "getField @k" on "obj" as well as "Maybe obj"
I'm trying to write HTML form helpers where I'd like the call-sites to support both of the following use-cases:
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes, DataKinds, OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Proxy
import Data.Text as Text
import GHC.Generics
import GHC.Records
import GHC.TypeLits

data FormCtx obj = FormCtx { ctxFieldNamePrefix :: !Text, ctxObject :: !obj } 
data MyRecord = MyRecord { field1 :: !Text, field2 :: !Text } deriving (Generic)

-- USE-CASE #1
let ctx = FormCtx "MyRecord" obj
in (fieldNameFor @"field1" ctx, fieldValueFor @"field1" ctx)

-- USE-CASE #2 -- with a (Maybe obj)
let ctx = FormCtx "MyRecord" (Just obj)
in (fieldNameFor @"field1" ctx, fieldValueFor @"field1" ctx)

-- Implementation for fieldNameFor which works only 
-- with `obj`, and not `Maybe obj`
fieldNameFor :: forall k obj a . (KnownSymbol k, HasField k obj a) => FormCtx obj -> Text
fieldNameFor FormCtx {ctxFieldNamePrefix} = ctxFieldNamePrefix <> "[" <> (Text.pack $ symbolVal (Proxy @k)) <> "]"

-- Implementation for fieldValueFor which works only 
-- with `obj`, and not `Maybe obj`
fieldValueFor :: forall k obj a . (KnownSymbol k, HasField k obj a) => FormCtx obj -> a
fieldValueFor FormCtx {ctxObject} = getField @k ctxObject

I've tried defining a type-classs, called FieldNameFor to be able to define overlapping instances for obj and Maybe obj but I'm unable to make it work with the KnownSymbol k, HasField k obj a typeclass constrains that are required for getField to work.

Why obj and Maybe obj rather than MyRecord and Maybe MyRecord?

@DanielWagner yes - you are right. Technically getField needs to work with MyRecord and Maybe MyRecord whereas fieldNameFor needs to work with obj and Maybe obj (which would somehow use getField internally)

What should fieldValueFor @"field1" (FormCtx "MyRecord" Nothing) return?

@JosephSible-ReinstateMonica case #1: fieldValueFor @"field1" (FormCtx "MyRecord" Nothing) = Nothing ; case #2: fieldValueFor @"field1" (FormCtx "MyRecord" (Just myRec)) = Just $ getField @"field1" myRec

So you want it to always return a Maybe a rather than an a, whether or not the obj was wrapped in a Maybe?

@JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I've edited my previous comment to make the intent clearer. Please see if it makes more sense now?

So should fieldValueFor @"field1" (FormCtx "MyRecord" myRec) return getField @"field1" myRec (as it does now) or Just $ getField @"field1" myRec?

Also, would it be acceptable if it worked with Identity obj and Maybe obj, instead of obj and Maybe obj?

@JosephSible-ReinstateMonica if that's the only way possible to implement something like this... although I wonder what pain it would introduce in every call site that needs to use ctxObject. Would it still be possible to do ctx ^. object . someLens instead of ctx ^. object . identity . someLens ?

This isn't very pretty, but it works. Just replace your existing fieldValueFor with it:
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

type family CopyMaybe a b where
    CopyMaybe (Maybe a) b = Maybe b
    CopyMaybe a b = b

class FieldValueFor k obj a where
    fieldValueFor :: FormCtx obj -> CopyMaybe obj a

instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} (KnownSymbol k, HasField k obj a, CopyMaybe obj a ~ a) => FieldValueFor k obj a where
    fieldValueFor FormCtx {ctxObject} = getField @k ctxObject

instance (KnownSymbol k, HasField k obj a) => FieldValueFor k (Maybe obj) a where
    fieldValueFor FormCtx {ctxObject} = getField @k <$> ctxObject

For fieldNameFor it's even simpler: just remove the HasField k obj a constraint (it was redundant all along), and then your existing implementation will work.
